# placeholder doesn't work with input, having type='number' in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, placeholder

Here is my example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>«Bug»</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style type="text/css">
        input[type='number'] {
            background: gray;
        }
        input[type='number']::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            color: red;
        }
        input[type='number']::-moz-placeholder {
            color: red;
        }
        input[type='number']:-ms-input-placeholder {
            color: red;
        }
        input[type='number']::placeholder {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
    <input type="number" placeholder="buggy bug">
</body>
</html>
```

You can also check it here: http://g1un.ru/bug/bug.html 
I also did a "pen" http://codepen.io/g1un/pen/GmzaEg but it sometimes works as it should, when via first link it's always buggy.
I'm trying to style input placeholder with type='number'. But in firefox (53.0.3) it has no effect.
Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

In your codepen, turn on autoprefixer in the CSS cog.

```
input[type='number'] {
  background: gray;
  &::placeholder {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Type this - and then look at the CSS output of the CSS pane with the `V` icon.

This will help you see the right prefixes.

```
input[type='number'] {
  background: gray;
}
input[type='number']::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
input[type='number']::-moz-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
input[type='number']:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
input[type='number']::placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

Another note - in your example above, your `<style>` tag should be in the `<head>` -

Comment: thanks. I have updated my code here http://g1un.ru/bug/bug.html according to your answer. But still no effect. Just have noted that if I open and when close devtools the style begin to work.